# django rest framework url parameters getting combined

Tags: python, django, rest, github, frameworks

I have the following in my urls.py:

`url(r'^prstatus/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<organization>.+)/' +
        '(?P<repository>.+)/(?P<pr>\d+)/$',PRStatus.get_pr_status, name="one_pr_in_repo"),`

The url that I enter is:
`localhost:8000/api/v1/prstatus/1/myrepo/docker-react/1`

But if I `print(organization, repository, pr)`.
I get `myrepo/docker-react 2 None`

Organization gets assigned **myrepo/docker-react** instead of **myrepo**.

Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that

```
r'^prstatus/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<organization>.+)/' + '(?P<repository>.+)/(?P<pr>\d+)/$'
```

is regular expression. The [python documentation for regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) explains:

> The '*', '+', and '?' qualifiers are all greedy; they match as much text as possible. Sometimes this behaviour isn’t desired; if the RE `<.*>` is matched against `'<a> b <c>'`, it will match the entire string, and not just `'<a>'`. Adding ? after the qualifier makes it perform the match in non-greedy or minimal fashion; as few characters as possible will be matched. Using the RE `<.*?>` will match only `'<a>'`.

Because `.` matches any character, including `\`, you need to replace `.+` by `.+?`

Another option is to change `.` to something that better reflects which characters should be matched. Every organization and repository name I know of only contains alphanumeric characters, underscores and whitespaces (which are replaced by dashes in urls), so this will probably work:

```
r'^prstatus/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<organization>[\w-]+)/(?P<repository>[\w-]+)/(?P<pr>\d+)/$'
```

Comment: I tried the above one still gave me the same issue. I did notice one thing that the regex works a few times and doesn't work the rest of the times. If I keep hitting the same API call again and again 1 out of 10 requests get processed correctly: paramaters get correct values, but rest of the times it gives me the issue mentioned in the question.
I added a workaround where I split the value in organization into organization and repository. :(
Not sure if this is a bug.

Comment: @AratiKulkarni I do not know if you are experiencing a bug, but be sure to debug every parameter. A regular expression should match the same string in the same way every time. Maybe there is only a difference of a `\` at the end of a string, that decides wether it works like you want it to or not.